# What happens if I separate a dwarf from his favorite shield?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Our militia commander just got attached to a silly oaken buckler.  I was planning on upgrading him to a steel shield.  What will happen if I forcibly separate him from his shield?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing bad will really happen. The best case is that once you unforbid it, he'll just put it in a storage container that he owns. Worst case he'll go grab it again.